# document.getElementsByClassName mostrar antes

Tags: javascript

Queria que mostrasse quantas classes "twitter-tweet" tem no html na parte de cima, e não na parte de baixo.
se eu coloco na parte de cima aparece "0 videos" e se eu coloco na parte de baixo aparece a quantidade certa.

```html
<head>
<title>Passinho</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<br><br><br><h1>Passinho: <script>
var len = document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-tweet").length;
document.write(len);
console.log(len);
</script> videos</h1><br><br><br>   <-- aqui fica 0 videos

<!-- 64 -->
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="pt" dir="ltr">ESSE VÍDEO É VICIANTE  <a href="https://twitter.co/blLqQhWes6">pic.twitter.com/blLqQhWes6</a></p>&mdash; PASSINHOS E DANCINHAS (@ilovepassinhorj) <a href="https://twitter.com/ilovepassinhorj/status/1205874013920206850?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">December 14, 2019</a></blockquote> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<!-- 63 -->
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="und" dir="ltr"> <a href="https://twitter.co/orvqANs3VQ">pic.twitter.com/orvqANs3VQ</a></p>&mdash; Bia Das Dancinhas (@Ofcquebradeira) <a href="https://twitter.com/Ofcquebradeira/status/1207007235563499520?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">December 17, 2019</a></blockquote> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<!-- 61 -->
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="pt" dir="ltr">Já que pedirammm ‍♂️<br>Tivemos que quebrar <a href="https://twitter.com/eilaryssamoraes?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">@eilaryssamoraes</a> <a href="https://twitter.co/Sp3dipMm0o">pic.twitter.com/Sp3dipMm0o</a></p>&mdash; Lc Quebradeira (@lucasalveslc1) <a href="https://twitter.com/lucasalveslc1/status/1201655334496067586?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">December 3, 2019</a></blockquote> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<br><br><br><h1>Passinho: <script>
var len = document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-tweet").length;
document.write(len);
console.log(len);
</script> videos</h1><br><br><br> <-- aqui mostra a quantidade certa de videos
queria fazer isso só que na parte lá de cima no primeiro <h1>
```

Answer (score 4):

É porque os elementos não existem ou não foram renderizados antes do primeiro script, ou seja eles só existem depois do primeiro script, logo ou você usa o evento load para checa quando a página carregou:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var len = document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-tweet").length;
    console.log(len);
});
```

Ou prefira o evento `DOMContentLoeaded` (é um evento do objeto `document`) que não irá precisar que tudo carregue (como imagens e outros scripts), apenas o HTML:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var len = document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-tweet").length;
    console.log(len);
});
```